# check if a set of key and value exist in a variant column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to form a SQL query to loop over a JSON input structure and check the key -value pair exists in the variant column

```
for key in (select object_keys(json_input)) loop
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE EXISTS(json_input, key) AND key = value;
end for ;
```

Comment: By "exists" do you mean anywhere in the JSON including nested one or more levels deep?

Comment: @GregPavlik there is one level deep json so no nesting,basically want to check if  select * from table where variant_column["input_key"] = input_value; if there are 2 or more key value pair to be searched then it will be appended as dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON is not multi-level, you can just use a regular where clause. There's no need to use an exists clause. If the JSON key does not exist in the JSON (third example in the sample data) it will not pass the predicate in the where clause:

```
with JSON as
(
select parse_json('{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}') as V
  union all
select parse_json('{"name":"Dave", "age":32, "car":null}') as V
  union all
select parse_json('{"name2":"John", "age":30, "car":null}') as V
)
select * from JSON where V:name = 'John'
;
```

| V |
| --- |
| { "age": 30, "car": null, "name": "John" } |